# Read LED state without using switch or relay

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

This is a very silly question. I am a newbie in Electronics and Arduino. I want to know if i can get the current status of LED which is connected with a 9V battery.

I'm using NodeMCU v3 Wifi.

I tried to read using digitalRead but it is always returning 1 no matter what.

```
int ledPin = 13; 
int inPin = 12; 
int val = 0;  

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  val = digitalRead(inPin); 
  digitalWrite(ledPin, val);  
}
```

All i want to know is, If i turn ON some equipment using nodemcu/arduino over WiFi, Is there any way to check that the equipment is really ON?

Comment: explain your circuit. how do you switch the LED? what are your pins connected to?

Comment: LED1 positive is connected to resistor 9V battery positive and LED1 ground is connected to the battery ground. I want to check using arduino if LED1 is on or off. So i connected LED1 positive to pin 12 of my esp8266 to perform digitalRead() but i guess i'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: first of all esp and led must share GND, otherwise you cannot measure the voltage. then you have to be careful not to fry your esp if you're probing around 9V circuits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to check that the equipment is really ON?

Depending on the kind of device you can:

a) measure the current through the device

b) sense the device (light, heat, ...)

c) measure the voltage across the device

d) try to communicate with the device

e) ...

Comment: I appreciate your response but i already managed to get temperature sensor data but i want to turn my machine on or off based on that data which i can do. Only thing  i want to know is there any feedback mechanism which will let us know that machine is actually turned on or off.

Comment: yeah and I told you what you can do to achieve that. what is unclear?

Comment: I want to turn off Air Conditioner through PHP. I'm able to do that as well. But sometimes it might happen that i Click on ON button but machine is not turned on. Something might go wrong in between e.g. power outage. Hence i want to know is there any way to check from Machine end that it is ON or OFF?

Comment: @sanathjaysurya pick something from my list. measure the current through the AC, measure the voltage across the AC, sense airflow, temperature gradient, humidity or whatever,  given the electronics knowledge you present here I'd strongly advise you to stay away from mains voltage!!!!! you will probably die